# how to create a random bit64 value

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am having trouble trying to generate a random unsigned __int64 value, does anyone have a quick and effective way of doing something like this? below is what i am doing, check the code below.

```
unsigned __int64 m_RandomKey = 0;

while(m_RandomKey == 0)
{
    m_RandomKey = (unsigned __int64) rand() << 32 | rand();
}
```

What is the best way to generate a unsigned __int64 key so that is is hard to get the same key again after a while or even at all? **it doesn't have to be unique** as long as there remains a 1 in 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 chance of it not doing it again!

Comment: Might be helpful: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution

Comment: `rand` is not required to generate 32-bit values. It generates values in the range `[0, RAND_MAX]`, and `RAND_MAX` must be >= 32767. A slightly more sophisticated algorithm can adjust for this.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using C++11, you can use `std::mt19937_64`, a native 64 bits implementation of the Mersenne twister algorithm.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random.

It is available in Visual C++ 2010 and 2012 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee462314(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think your method is fast, portable and good enough. As long as you initialise the random seed well this should work very well. Rand() may not be a perfect uniform distribution but it is pretty close.

As @Pete mentions below the Rand() is only sure to work across a 16 bit number so a slightly more complex expression might be better for true portability:
 m_RandomKey = (unsigned __int64)( (rand() << 48) | (rand() << 32)| (rand() << 16)|rand());

Still fast and definitely better.

Comment: But the algorithm assumes that `rand` generates a 32-bit value, which is not guaranteed. 16-bits is the minimum that's required.

Comment: Still not right, though. If `int` is smaller than 48 bits the new version has undefined behavior. Adding a cast to `unsigned __int64` to the return value of each of the calls to `rand` will fix this, but if `RAND_MAX` is larger than 2^16 - 1 it wastes bits. I'm not trying to pick on you, just pointing out that writing good random number generators is not simple. Knuth experimented with what seems like a reasonable one: use a random number generator to randomly pick one of eight (if I remember correctly) different generators to generate the next value; turned out it was horrible.